# Stop appending ints to a list after a specified sum is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking to create a loop that takes a max sum, then continually asks the user to input a number till the max sum is reached. However I wanted to make it so that entering " " would break the code, and the user would still be able to input numbers after the max sum was reached but they just wouldn't append to the numList list. Thanks!

```
maxSum = int(input("Max sum: "))

numInput = 0
numList = []

while numInput != "":
    numInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    numList.append(numInput)
    if sum(numList) > maxSum:
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Why are you `raise StopIteration`? I think you just want `break`

Comment: what would be the point off continuing an input of numbers once you have reached the end i.e. the sum of values in `numList` is greater than the `maxSum`, it won't be appended anymore and you won't see those extra numbers unless you change the logic of the last `if` statement. But like the first comment mentioned, just `break` instead.

Comment: @FishingCode It is part of an assignment

Comment: Okay, so. You read in an integer, and if the list sum has already reached the threshold, you want not to add it to the list. In other words: if the list sum has *not* reached the threshold, you want to add it to the list. So, `if`... what comes after that?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this condition to while `sum(numList) < maxSum` and I created a function for taking user input it will keep  asking user for input untill user enters valid input.

```
maxSum = int(input("Max sum: "))

numList =  []

def valid_input():
    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num.isnumeric() or num == '':
            return num
        else:
            print('Enter valid number: ')

while sum(numList) < maxSum:
    numInput = valid_input()
    if numInput != '':
        numList.append(int(numInput))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Your solution does not address the other part of the question (empty string).

Answer (score 1):

Try including a flag of some sort or a just use `break':

```
maxSum = int(input("Max sum: "))

numInput = 0
numList = []

while True:
  numInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  numList.append(numInput)
  if sum(numList) > maxSum and numInput != "":
     break
# using a flag
v = True
while v:
  numInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  numList.append(numInput)
  if sum(numList) > maxSum and numInput == "":
     v = False
```

Comment: `numInput != ""` is always true because `numInt` is a number. Also, `int()` will fail on a non-numeric input.

Comment: `if sum(numList) > maxSum and numInput == "":` i think you should use `or`